# RSA 2048 Encryption Decryption - Exception

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt the data with RSA 2048.

We have one public key and private key and will be using same throughout.
but the problem is, when I decrypt, I am getting javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero

```
File file = new File("C:\\temp-ldi\\pubkey.txt");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
file.createNewFile();
encryptedText = RSACrypto.encrypt("PLAIN TEXT"); //no argument of pub-key, generate key pair
writer.write(new BASE64Encoder().encode(RSACrypto.pubKeyToBytes(RSACrypto.publicKey)));
writer.close();
file = new File("C:\\temp-ldi\\privkey.txt");
writer = new FileWriter(file);
file.createNewFile();
writer.write(new BASE64Encoder().encode(RSACrypto.privKeyToBytes(RSACrypto.privateKey)));
writer.close();
```

then I am using below code to decrypt the data

```
File privfile = new File("C:\\temp-ldi\\privkey.txt");
File pubfile = new File("C:\\temp-ldi\\pubkey.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(pubfile);
// file.createNewFile();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String s;
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(s);
}
br.close();
reader.close();
this.encryptedText = RSACrypto.encrypt("PLAIN TEXT", sb.toString());
reader = new FileReader(privfile);
br = new BufferedReader(reader);
sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(s);
}
br.close();
reader.close();
System.out.println(RSACrypto.decrypt(this.encryptedText, sb.toString()));
```

all the encryption/decryption string will return in Base64Encoder/Base64Decoder format.

How do I pass the private key from file/simple string so that the key is not modified.

**Update**
RSACrypto class : http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?83517f2b3db94d24#Sdu12/vXPuxa5AxO95FPgKSF6N40R2DzD6lwQkvroyE=

Comment: please show code of RSACrypto class.

Comment: you save private key in file `prikey.txt`, but read it from `privkey.txt`

Comment: just typo while pasting. reading from same file. assume the folder is having no other files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, problem in RSACrypto. When you encrypt file, it creates every time new keypair (in `encrypt`). Just remove new keypair generation from encrypt, call `newKeyPair` direcly, when you need it. 
And that static variables does no good for multi-thread environment.

I'll suggest to throw RSACrypto class, or rewrite it at least. I don't know why you so afraid of using byte[] type and why you need everything be BASE64 encoded. Code will a lot simple without additional encoding/decoding.

Here is working example (without RSACrypto), you can use it as template:

```
    File file = new File("C:\\temp-ldi\\pubkey.txt");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    file.createNewFile();
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    generator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
    KeyPair keyPayr = generator.generateKeyPair();
    writer.write(new BASE64Encoder().encode(keyPayr.getPublic().getEncoded()));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    file = new File("C:\\temp-ldi\\privkey.txt");
    writer = new FileWriter(file);
    file.createNewFile();
    writer.write(new BASE64Encoder().encode(keyPayr.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();


    File privfile = new File("C:\\temp-ldi\\privkey.txt");
    File pubfile = new File("C:\\temp-ldi\\pubkey.txt");
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(pubfile);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String s;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    br.close();
    reader.close();
    PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(sb.toString())));
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    String encryptedText = new BASE64Encoder().encode(cipher.doFinal("PLAIN TEXT".getBytes("UTF-8")));
    System.out.println("encrypted: " + encryptedText);
    reader = new FileReader(privfile);
    br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    br.close();
    reader.close();
    PrivateKey privateKey =  KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(sb.toString())));
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    System.out.println( new String(cipher.doFinal (new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedText))));
```